# Parse CMD arguments and call method in class using DI

Tags: java, spring, scala

I would like to parse CMD arguments and if a given string is provided, call a method in a class that uses dependency injection.

I am parsing the CMD args from the SpringBootApplication main method

```
object SpringbootApplication extends Logger {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[SpringbootApplication], args :_ *)
    val job = args(0)
    if(job == "prod") {
      // somehow call runPipelineJob
    }
```

The method I'd like to call is in another class:

```
@Component
class PipelineMain @Autowired()(
  val jobRunnerService: JobRunnerService) {

  def runPipelineJob(): Unit = {
    jobRunnerService.process()
  }
  runPipelineJob()
```

Would like to call that `runPipelineJob`

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

You could use some sort of event listener and make use of [`ApplicationArguments`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationArguments.html) which holds args passed to Spring Boot application instance. In Java it would look like :

```
@Component
public class Listeners {

    private final PipelineMain pipelineMain;
    private final ApplicationArguments applicationArguments;

    @Autowired
    public Listeners(final PipelineMain pipelineMain, final ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) {
        this.pipelineMain = pipelineMain;
        this.applicationArguments = applicationArguments;
    }

    //react to ApplicationStartedEvent 
    @EventListener
    public void handleApplicationStarted(ApplicationStartedEvent applicationStartedEvent) {
        String[] args = applicationArguments.getSourceArgs();
        if(args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("prod")) {
            pipelineMain.runPipelineJob();
        }
    }

}
```

### Solution 2

Or you could also achieve this using by implementing the [`ApplicationRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html) interface :

```
@Component
public class AppStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    private final PipelineMain pipelineMain;

    @Autowired
    public AppStartupRunner(final PipelineMain pipelineMain) {
        this.pipelineMain = pipelineMain;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {
        String[] args = applicationArguments.getSourceArgs();
        if(args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("prod")) {
            pipelineMain.runPipelineJob();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm looking for a Scala solution and not sure how to initialize the PipelineMain. Here you just declare a variable that's undefined at first but, in Scala can't really do that...

Comment: @Crt `PipelineMain` should be available through the application context for DI. So either you annotate it with spring stereotype like `@Component` or create a `@Bean` in configuration.

Comment: I tried the @Component annotation and it makes PipelineMain run automatically. However, i'd like to control whether or not it gets called based on CMD args. Is there a way to control the @Component?

Comment: That means that something actually calls the `runPipelineJob` but from the code that you provided it is impossible to deduce what it is. Maybe there is other spring bean that calls this service? If so - you should inject `ApplicationArguments` there and perform verification of args and launch the `runPipelineJob` or not.

Comment: Update the code snippet. Hope that makes it clearer.